# Sql LIKE in Arabic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

Consider this sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(name nvarchar(MAX))

INSERT INTO #tempTable VALUES (N'إِبْرَاهِيمُ'), (N'إبراهيم')

SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE name = N'إبراهيم'
SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE name LIKE N'%إبراهيم%'
```

Both selects only return `إبراهيم` but not `إِبْرَاهِيمُ`. How can I make it ignore these non-alphabetical characters in search? In other words, I want to get all similar words, including those with non-alpha characters.

Comment: Don't the accent characters make the characters different? Meaning 'م' is not the same as 'مُ'?

Comment: Try to use SOUNDEX, however I'm not sure SQL Server supports Arabic for that function.

Comment: No, they are used only to indicate the "sound" they are spoken with. For example `مَ` sounds `ma`, while `مِ` sounds `me`.

Comment: there is another link here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ArabicSoundex.aspx

Comment: A wild guess (I've never used arabic): could you use an accent insensitive collation?

Comment: @HansKesting Like `Arabic_CI_AI`? I have tried with no effect! I need to contact Microsoft to ask what is the meaning of "accent insensitive"? Because it didn't help with my case

Answer (score 0):

You do not do it. Simple. NOTHING about arabic here - you have the same problem in english.

> How can I make it ignore these non-alphabetical characters in search?

Like numbers? NOT AT ALL. Not with "standard SQL Syntax".

If you can, put a full text index on the field. And use the full text search syntax in your query. This is what it is for.

Comment: No. I was misunderstood. I mean with "non-alphabetical characters" those like `ضَ` and `ضِ` and `ضُ`. As you see, the same alphabetical character is used, with some trailing mark indicating how to sound the character, without changing the character itself

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread over at sql stackexchange that has a workaround for this issue.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14153/treating-certain-arabic-characters-as-identical

Comment: Thank you, but this is different. Your link tells how to search with "similar characters. Example `أ`, `ا`, `ء`, `ؤ`. All these pronounced `Aa`. I am speaking about `ضَ`, `ضِ`, `ضُ` (which are pronounced `dha`, `dhe`, `dho`).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no case sensitive Arabic language, and of course, both select statements will return 'إبراهيم' because they were ordered to do that.

This is a problem we have been suffering from for a very long time, people always look for 'احمد' when it's written 'أحمد' and they won't find it.

Comment: I think your problem is answered by Kramb answer

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution 100%:

```
$yourChaine = \Transliterator::create('NFC; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC')
                                ->transliterate($yourChaine);
```

Comment: Hello, can you please elaborate on this? I really don't understand this, not mentioning I don't know what language it is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that SQL Server is treating the Arabic letters in the names as different characters due to the added diacritic marks. To make the searches ignore those marks and match on just the base alphabetic characters, you can use a collation that is accent/case insensitive:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable 
(
  name nvarchar(MAX) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
)

INSERT INTO #tempTable VALUES (N'إِبْرَاهِيمُ'), (N'إبراهيم')

SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE name = N'إبراهيم'

SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE name LIKE N'%إبراهيم%'
```

By specifying Arabic_CI_AS as the collation on the name column, both queries will now return both rows, since that collation will treat characters with diacritics as identical to the base letter.

The key points are:

Use a case-insensitive, accent-insensitive collation like Arabic_CI_AS
Apply the collation at the column level when you define the table. Make sure to use the same collation when comparing/searching the column.

This allows you to find matches regardless of diacritic marks or case differences in the Arabic text.